# Control QLoggingCategory in PyQt 5.6

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5.6

Some log output from Qt is controlled by [the category logging](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html) (eg. The JavaScript console output on `QWebEnginePage`).

The `QLoggingCategory` in C++ can be used for that, but there isn't the same class in PyQt5.

Is there any way to control the category logging in PyQt5, or mute them all?

Comment: I don't understand the question - what do you mean with "control the category logging"? Could you show an example of what you'd do in C++?

Comment: You might want to contact PyQt [on their mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) which is their primary support way.

Answer (score 0):

Not a straight solution, but you can create something like this:

```
class MyPage (QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, message, lineNumber, sourceId):
        #Send the log entry to Python's logging or do whatever you want
        logging.info("level: {}, source: {}, "+
                 "line: {}, message: {}".format(level,
                                                sourceId,
                                               lineNumber,
                                               message))
```

Then replace the default page of the QWebEngineView:

```
self.page = MyPage(owner)
self.browser.setPage(self.page)
```